# Multiple indices in ggplot label

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I would like to add a label containing multiple indices to a bar plot:

```
data<-as.data.frame(c("A"))
colnames(data)<-"A"
data$B<-5

ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=B)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge", size=0.25, width=0.8, alpha=0.8) +
  annotate("text", x=1, y=2.5, label="some text")
```

I need to replace "some text" with "a1 a2 a3" where the numbers are in subscript. I tried the following but get errors:

```
annotate("text", x=1, y=0.4, parse=T, label=paste("a[1]","a[2]","a[3]",sep="     "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does that:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge", size=0.25, width=0.8, alpha=0.8) + annotate("text", x=1, y=2.5, label="~a[1]~a[2]~a[3]", parse=TRUE)
```